# How to zip two 1d numpy array to 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy 1d arrays, e.g:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([6,7,8,9,10])
```

Then how can I get one 2d array `[[1,6], [2,7], [3,8], [4,9], [5, 10]]`?

Comment: For very small arrays, `zip` can be faster than calling Numpy functions, but for longer arrays the Numpy functions are _much_ faster, with `column_stack` being the fastest in my tests. Eg, for arrays of length 1000, `column_stack` is about 1000 times faster than `zip`. [Here's some relevant timeit code](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/a4d0540f960a80fde91fa808eaa88700).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The answer lies in your question:

```
np.array(list(zip(a,b)))
```

**Edit:**

Although my post gives the answer as requested by the OP, the conversion to list and back to NumPy array takes some overhead (noticeable for large arrays).

Hence, `dstack` would be a computationally efficient alternative  (ref. @zipa's answer).  I was unaware of `dstack` at the time of posting this answer so credits to @zipa for introducing it to this post.

**Edit 2:**

As can be seen in the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730044/converting-two-lists-into-a-matrix), [`np.c_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) is even shorter than `np.dstack`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(1, 6)
>>> b = np.arange(6, 11)
>>> 
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> b
array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
>>> np.c_[a, b]
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4,  9],
       [ 5, 10]])
```

Comment: Why use plain Python functions to do this when you're working with Numpy arrays?

Comment: @PM2Ring You're right. I was unaware of zipa's answer but was the first to post.

Comment: I don't like someone mixing two types of list when doing operations.

Answer (score 170):

If you have numpy arrays you can use [`dstack()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([6,7,8,9,10])

c = np.dstack((a,b))
#or
d = np.column_stack((a,b))

>>> c
array([[[ 1,  6],
        [ 2,  7],
        [ 3,  8],
        [ 4,  9],
        [ 5, 10]]])
>>> d
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4,  9],
       [ 5, 10]])

>>> c.shape
(1, 5, 2)
>>> d.shape
(5, 2)
```

Comment: Alternatively, `np.stack((a, b), axis=-1)`, but your way is more compact.

Comment: FWIW, `np.column_stack` appears to be the fastest way to do this, see my comment on the question for details.

Comment: Just a note - `np.dstack` stacks arrays in the 3rd dimension. thus you'd be creating an unnecessary dimension. `np.column_stack`, or `np.stack(...,axis=-1)` are both more appropriate.

Comment: Why `axis=-1` and not `+1`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zip`

```
np.array(list(zip(a,b)))
array([[ 1,  6],
   [ 2,  7],
   [ 3,  8],
   [ 4,  9],
   [ 5, 10]])
```

Comment: how is this different to @Ebe's answer?

Comment: Well we both answered at the same time, i was almost 2-3 seconds late

Comment: Why use plain Python functions to do this when you're working with Numpy arrays?

Comment: sure, i will go with @zipa's answer