# Filling an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to fill an array with some number, the output should be like this:

```
[[x1, y1, z1],
 [x1, y2, z2],
 [x2, y1, z3],
 [x2, y2, z4],
 [x3, y1, z5],
 [x3, y2, z6]]
```

I have the data x, y, and z (lists) with 3 values x, 2 values of y and 6 values of z inside the data.

I tried to create a new array and then fill it with for or while loop, but I can't get it fully filled.

How can I do it in numpy with python without filling it manually?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44409182/7957705 is maybe what you are looking for

Comment: @FatihKılıç I don't think it is, in his case, the output will be `[[a1 b1] [a2 b2] ... [a5 b5]]`. In my case, I want to pair each x with each y. Also, my data actually much larger than 2 x and 2 y

Comment: @Amri Rasyidi is there a typo in your output? The first column is x1,x1,x2,x2 or should it be x1,x2,x1,x2 ?

Comment: @AndyK nope, it is the output I want. Pair each x with each y that have z value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [np.repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [np.tile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) on x and y respectively to get the desired columns and then stacking them together with z into one array:

```
import numpy as np

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5]
z = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

a = np.array([np.repeat(x, 2), np.tile(y, 3), z]).T
```

result:

```
array([[ 1,  4,  6],
       [ 1,  5,  7],
       [ 2,  4,  8],
       [ 2,  5,  9],
       [ 3,  4, 10],
       [ 3,  5, 11]])
```

Comment: I checked the dtype and it returns 'U10', can I still have the number format of the data?

Comment: @Amri Rasyidi what is your data like? Are the values of x,y and z of the same type? Are their values strings? It still should work.

Comment: I've found the solution to that dtype problem. I cast it into array then use astype to change the data type. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For a pure Python solution, to work with any list size.

```
x = [11,12,13,14,15]
y = [21,23,24]
z = [31,32,33,34,35,36,37]
```

This verbose code:

```
tmp = []
for i in range(max(len(x), len(y), len(z))):
    for yy in y:
        tmp.append([x[i%len(x)], yy])

for i in range(len(tmp)):
    tmp[i].append((z[i%len(z)]))
```

Returns

```
# [[11, 21, 31],
#  [11, 23, 32],
#  [11, 24, 33],
#  [12, 21, 34],
#  [12, 23, 35],
#  [12, 24, 36],
#  [13, 21, 37],
#  [13, 23, 31],
#  [13, 24, 32],
#  [14, 21, 33],
#  [14, 23, 34],
#  [14, 24, 35],
#  [15, 21, 36],
#  [15, 23, 37],
#  [15, 24, 31],
#  [11, 21, 32],
#  [11, 23, 33],
#  [11, 24, 34],
#  [12, 21, 35],
#  [12, 23, 36],
#  [12, 24, 37]]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've edited my question. Does it work with different size list of x and y?

Comment: @AmriRasyidi I edited leaving only the pure Python option do work with different sizes of any list.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using NumPy's `meshgrid` function to create a grid of all combinations of your x, y, and z values. Then, you can use `numpy.column_stack` to stack these arrays horizontally.

```
import numpy as np

# Your data
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2]
z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# Create a grid of all combinations
x_grid, y_grid, z_grid = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij')

# Reshape the grids to 1D arrays
x_flat = x_grid.flatten()
y_flat = y_grid.flatten()
z_flat = z_grid.flatten()

# Stack the arrays horizontally to create the final array
result_array = np.column_stack((x_flat, y_flat, z_flat))

print(result_array)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Decomposing the problem

Suppose `X = [x_1,x_2,...,x_n]`, `Y = [y_1,y_2,...,x_m]` and `Z=[z_1,z_2,...,z_nm]`, you want to:

1. pair every X with every Y, first varying Y
2. then pair the resulting sequence with Z, one by one, on the order they appear.

## Cartesian product of X and Y

Pairing X and Y can be done using the [product method from itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.product), as in:

```py
from itertools import product
X=[1,2]
Y=[3,4,5]
print(list(product(X,Y)))
```

This will return `[(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]`

The itertools library doesn't return a list, but an iterable, so we can compose these iterables.

## Pairing XY with Z

Now we have `XY = [(x1,y_1), (x1,y_2), ... (x_1,y_m), (x_2, y_1), (x_2, y_2), ... , (x_2, y_m), ..., (x_n,y_m)]` with n*m elements, and we want to pair them, respectively to `Z=[z_1,z_2, ..., z_nm]`, to do that we can use a [builtin function called zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) which will pair them.

```py
from itertools import product
X=[1,2]
Y=[3,4,5]
Z="abcdef"
XY=product(X,Y)
print(list(zip(XY, Z)))
```

## Fixing the form

The last code will return `[((1, 3), 'a'), ((1, 4), 'b'), ((1, 5), 'c'), ((2, 3), 'd'), ((2, 4), 'e'), ((2, 5), 'f')]`. There is a slight deviation in the form: entries are on the form `((x,y),z)` instead of `[x,y,z]`, but we can fix that using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
from itertools import product
X=[1,2]
Y=[3,4,5]
Z="abcdef"
print([[x,y,z] for (x,y), z in zip(product(X,Y), Z)])
```