# Array combining in python

Tags: python

I tried to combine value from two one-dim arrays to make something like [(a, b), (c, d), (e, f)...]. However, I get a different result when I use list(zip(array1, array2)), and I have no clue why? The first picture is what I expected and the second picture is what I got.

```
def generate_data(self):

    #For train
    peak_ground_acc_train = np.random.uniform(low=1.0, high=50.0, size=100) #y-axis
    distance_train = np.arange(1, len(peak_ground_acc_train)+1) #x-axis

    magnitude = np.random.uniform(low=3.5, high=9.0, size=100)
    sample_label = magnitude

    #For test
    peak_ground_acc_test = np.random.uniform(low=1.0, high=50.0, size=100) #y-axis
    distance_test = np.arange(0, len(peak_ground_acc_test)) #x-axis

    train_data = list(zip(distance_train, peak_ground_acc_train))
    test_data = list(zip(distance_test, peak_ground_acc_test))

    plt.plot(distance_train, peak_ground_acc_train, 'b')
    plt.plot(train_data, 'r')
    plt.show()

    return train_data, sample_label, test_data
```

[What I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5c4z.png)

[What I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXFys.png)

Comment: Please include your expected and actual results as text in the question, rather than linking to screenshots.

Comment: `list(zip(...))` does what you want, but the problem seems to be that your plot is wrong, and you are just guessing that the reason is because `list(zip(...))` gives the wrong result. What else could be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting two lists into a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730044/converting-two-lists-into-a-matrix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plot() expects the data parameters as scalars or one dimensional array-like values. Please see "Parameters" in the documentation:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot

It does accept two dimensional parameter, but treats each column as separate data series. Hence the straight line you see is the plot for column 1 and the other plot you see is for column 2.

Why are you passing the zipped data to the plot()? Why not :

```
plt.plot(distance_train, peak_ground_acc_train, 'r')
```