# What is the function to be used in numpy to obtain the following result

Tags: python, numpy

What is the function to be used in numpy to obtain the following result?

```
import numpy as np
store = np.array([0,0,1,2])
cost = np.array([1,11,12,13])
```

O/P

```
[[0,1],[0,11],[1,12],[2,13]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interweaving two numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347065/interweaving-two-numpy-arrays)

Comment: Please tag *all python related questions* with the generic [python] tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting two lists into a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730044/converting-two-lists-into-a-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

np.column_stack((store,cost))

will give the output as expected

Answer (score 0):

The function pack does this behaviour:

```
pack = zip(store, cost)
```

With this function you will get:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 11), (1, 12), (2, 13)]
```