# Reshape numpy array in python with adding a new index value

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm not really familiar in python in such transformations, but I need a help to transforming one 1D numpy array of shape eg. (17000) into 2D numpy array (17000, 2) in such way, that we will have such structure

```
1D array (value1, value2, value3, ..., value17000)
2D array ((1, value1), (2, value2), (3, value3), ... (17000, value17000))
```

so in short words add a new row that will have a number of index from specific order).
Is there any efficient way to do this transform without writing a code, that will iterate over all values and copy that, but maybe that will do it in one-line transform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = np.column_stack((np.arange(1, len(some_np_array) + 1), some_np_array))
```

**EDIT:** I removed my previous answer because I didn't know about `np.column_stack` until now. For further explanation, you might want to refer to [Converting two lists into a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730044/converting-two-lists-into-a-matrix)

Comment: Works nice, but I have another question, how can I make similar transform, when I have 2D array in shape (5000, 17000) and I need a transform to shape (5000,17000,2) in similar way to previous version?

Comment: @MiXen `np.expand_dims(some_np_array, axis=-1)`. The `axis` argument decides where the `2` in your shape is. For example `axis=1` would lead to a shape `(5000, 2, 17000)`. Here, `axis=-1` is more convenient than `axis=3` because it would also cover cases, where your array has more than `3` dimensions. `-1` represents always the last dimension.

Comment: *edit: Here, `axis=-1` is more convenient than `axis=2` ...

Comment: Okey, but I mean, that I want to transform my array adding a axis with index values, that you have done by first version from this topic.

Comment: @MiXen okay.. this is a little bit more advanced. I will write a separate answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a better solution for your second question but this would be one:

```
import functools
import numpy as np

def append_idx(arr, some_iter):    
    return np.column_stack((np.fromiter(some_iter, dtype=np.int_, count=len(arr)), arr))

some_iter = iter(np.arange(1, functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, some_np_array.shape) + 1))
result = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: append_idx(x, some_iter), axis=-1, arr=some_np_array)
```

Comment: Works better, but still I see some issue, don't know if it is a desired behaviour, but I see that first row has proper indexes, but the second row start from value 17000 etc. but I need to have indexes starting from 0 in the next rows. Maybe I'm not super clear in first question, but this is crucial thing.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I figured that by myself, thanks for help :)